# How can I disable my webcam?

Tags: webcam

I have an integrated webcam in my laptop. I know that it works and that ubuntu recognized it because at installation it asked if I wanted a photo taken for some kind of image associated with my account. When I look in system settings, I do not see any webcam in the hardware section. I would like to disable the webcam like you can do in Windows, but as I can't find it in my hardware section, how can I disable it? I cannot even unplug it as it is integrated into the monitor. Am I looking in the wrong place?? I am using 12.04

Comment: You do not see the webcam in the hardware section? Where are you looking at? What is the output of the lsusb command?

Comment: In case you want to do this for security reasons, consider disabling the webcam in the system's BIOS settings as disabling it in software won't stop an attacker to re-enable it.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

## How to disable all webcams:

1. Run (for pre ubuntu 18.04):

```
gksu gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Or run (for ubuntu 18.04 and later):

```
gedit admin:///etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

2. Then add...

```
blacklist uvcvideo
```

...at the bottom. Save the file and quit the text editor.

## How to disable a single webcam:

1. Find your webcam with `lsusb`. My output:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:0328 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp.
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:568c Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
Bus 001 Device 042: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

If it isn't clear which device is your webcam, you can try `lsusb -t` and look for `Class=Video` or `Driver=uvcvideo` or similar to guess which one it is. My output:

```
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/6p, 5000M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/12p, 480M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 42, If 2, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 42, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 42, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 5: Dev 2, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 5: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 7: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 7: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
```

2. Next, find the vendor id and device id from the output of `lsusb` surrounding the colon:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:568c Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
```

So in my case, the vendor id is `0bda` and the product id is `568c`.

3. Next go to:

```
cd /sys/bus/usb/devices/
```

4. To find the correct directory do a `grep` there with the product id and if you get multiple results then also with the vendor id:

```
grep 568c */idProduct
```

returned:

```
1-5/idProduct:568c
```

and

```
grep 0bda */idVendor
```

returned:

```
1-5/idVendor:0bda
2-4/idVendor:0bda
```

In my case `1-5` is what I need.

5. `cd` into the directory from the previous step.
6. The file `bConfigurationValue` in this directory needs to contain a `0` to disable the device or a `1` to enable it. But this file is owned by root so to alter it (change the 0 to a 1 to enable) ...

```
echo 0 | sudo tee bConfigurationValue
```

...to disable. You can check the camera and it will be disabled.

7. This is not permanent yet. A reboot will set it back to what it was before. To make it permanent:

```
echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-5/bConfigurationValue
```

(where `1-5` is the directory we used and use a `1` to enable)

Comment: This disables _all_ webcams. The OP states that "I would like to disable the webcam like you can do in Windows..." Windows (through the Device Manager) enables _individual_ devices to be disabled and not an entire class of devices. It would be helpful if this answer was expanded to include instructions for disabling a _specific_ webcam.

Comment: "like you can do in Windows..." Windows (through the Device Manager)" I am expected to know what windows does? >:-D Is this sufficient?

Comment: Oh yes, that's much better :)

Comment: Dear Rinzwind,

would something like `# chmod a-r /dev/video0' work? just guessing!

Comment: yes but ONLY until you reboot. You are better of removing the user from the group video0 is set too. and there could also be a video1 or video2 if you have more camera's. Put some tape over the camera is a 100% foolproof trick ;) Or disabling it in BIOS if possible

Answer (score 65):

Cameras are controlled by the `uvcvideo` kernel module.

You can disable the camera until reboot by opening a terminal and typing `sudo modprobe -r uvcvideo`. You will be asked for your password, and after typing it, if there are no errors shown in the terminal, your webcam should be disabled.

If you got the error message: `modprobe: FATAL: Module uvcvideo is in use.` after trying to remove the uvcvideo module, you can try to force its removal with the following: `sudo rmmod -f uvcvideo` (thanks thiagowfx)

To enable your webcam again, type `sudo modprobe uvcvideo` into terminal.

If you want the camera to be disabled when you reboot, then press `ALT+F2` and paste this command:

```
gksu gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

You will be asked for your password. After giving it, a text file should open. Paste at the end of the text file on a new line:

```
blacklist uvcvideo
```

Then save the file and exit. Next time you start Ubuntu, the webcam should be disabled.

Comment: Much better comment. Thanks for letting me know how to disable right away, and mentioning restart required!

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer! I would like to add the following: if you got the error message: ```modprobe: FATAL: Module uvcvideo is in use.``` after trying to remove the uvcvideo module, you could try to force its removal with the following: ```sudo rmmod -f uvcvideo```.

Comment: Thank you, I want to bind to Fn+Esc a script that enable/disable camera and microphone, and this is what I need to know.

Comment: I know this answer is from 2012, but it is one of the top results on google and I don't have the reputation to answer here: gksu doesn't seem to be in Ubuntu 18 anymore, you just have to  do `sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` and add `blacklist uvcvideo`

Comment: Changing that file in Ubuntu 18.04 significantly slows down startup.

Comment: In my case (Debian 11, Gnome 3.38) restart is unnecessary, the webcam is disabled immediately

Comment: Any idea why the webcam can be used with virt-manager even if we disabled it on the host OS with modprobe?
Tested with Android-x86 on the guest OS by trying to link a device with QR code on WhatsApp: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1299754/using-webcam-and-microphone-in-virt-manager

Answer (score 43):

How about just taping it with some black colored tape? Take some black tape and put it on the webcam. Webcam disabled successfully! Unlike the answers above, this method works against malware attacks that try to enable your webcam as well!

Comment: This is actually a plausible solution and fool-proof.

Comment: @Gracchus Hmm. Transparent aluminum? Has that been invented yet? A hole in every hole! :P

Comment: Tape the microphone as well.

Comment: Well, no malware on Linux, but this solution is the best! no typing :))

Answer (score 2):

I had luck with going into the BIOS for my laptop (Dell XPS 15 9570), where there was an option to disable the built-in webcam and microphone.