# Block firefox from accessing webcam

Tags: firefox, webcam

I would like to disable the webcam for firefox.

My notebook has a built in webcam with awful quality, not only I don't want people I interact with on firefox to know that I do have a webcam, whenever i join hangouts it automatically starts to broadcast my webcam which i find specially unsettling.

I already applied a piece of tape covering the lens but i want to block firefox from even finding out that i do have a webcam.

is this possible?

I don't want to disable my webcam completely tho, I use it to skype every day.

Comment: Have you tried this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/166809/how-can-i-disable-my-webcam

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can block it for specific sites:

1. Write in address box `about:permissions` then <kbd>Enter</kbd>
2. Select target site
3. Use the camera: `Block`

Reference: [Mozilla Support Forum: What are the camera and microphone permissions?](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1011030)

[image: Firefox site permissions]

Other way:

1. Visit the target site
2. Right click → View Page Info → Permissions tab
3. Use the camera: Uncheck `Use default` then Choose `Block`

Reference: [MozillaZine: About protocol links](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About_protocol_links)

[image: Firefox site permissions 2]

Comment: Wow! Why the heck they bury such a nice configuration page under a non-discoverable place? Thanks!

Comment: @Rmano, actually there is direct way. see my update (2nd ref). I found it when I searched for other interesting `about:` pages

Comment: Thanks for such a good answer, what I really want tho, is to block Firefox from even knowing I have a webcam, it should be possible somehow

Comment: @Dolan, I agree there should be a way, may be it does need building from source. I will give it a try.