# Where is the flash whitelist and blacklist on Firefox?

Tags: firefox, flash

In `Tools--->Add-ons-->Plugins-->Shockwave Flash` I selected `Ask to activate`. Now I need to explicitly allow flash to play on every website I visit. It is possible to `Allow and Remember` or block flash permanently for particular websites. The question is where is this whitelist/blacklist located?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Check https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1011980 :

> by jscher2000 posted 7/23/14 7:46 AM
>
> When you are on the page, call up the Page Info dialog using one of
>   these methods:
>
> - right-click and choose View Page Info > Permissions
> - (menu bar) Tools > Page Info > Permissions
> - click the padlock or globe icon > More Information > Permissions
>
> You should find a list of permissions for each of your plugins. Can
>   you fix it there?

Comment: Looking for an entire list not per site permissions.

Answer (score 0):

A not user friendly solution to the problem is using an SQLite browser: `$ sudo apt-get install sqlitebrowser`.

Open the `permissions.sqlite` database with the browser and you'll find a single table called `moz_hosts`. This database is located within your user directory. Check [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data) on how to find it.

After opening the database select `type` with `contains`, and search for `flash`. You'll get a list of sites for which there are flash settings set. Looking at record 65 at the end of the image, you'll notice the type is `plugin:flash` and the permission is set to `2`. The values 1, 2 and 3 mean respectively *allow*, *block* and *always ask*. If a site has *use default* selected then there will be no record for it in the table.

These four options can be set for a specific site by using the third option in [Whocares](https://askubuntu.com/users/396031/whocares) answer, i.e. click padlock or globe, select more information and then permissions. Flash is at the top.

[image: SQLite browser w/ flash block]

Answer (score 0):

Been looking for a solution for this for ages too ...

Found it here (Ubuntu 12.04):

go to `~\.macromedia\FlashPlayer`

and you'll find some sub-folders containing URLs of websites to which were previously given permission ("allow and remember") but only after you've visited them in your current session. Apparently there is no list of all sites that were given permission.

However, this feature is part of firefox and not flash. So the permissions are handled in mozillas permission.sqlite file.

You can either delete this file to 'reset' your permissions or visit each site and follow bummis comment 606725.

Note: Mozilla might (temporarily) block this feature 'click-to-allow' for security reasons altogether, check https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/blocked/ for updates.

Answer (score -1):

Simply type:

```
about:permissions
```

into the address bar. This should pop up a window where you can choose these permissions.

Thanks hope this helps.

Comment: Although the `about:permissions` is useful, it doesn't show a flash permission there. I see the same as in the picture in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/553879/298314).

Comment: -1 Have you tried your solution itself?