# Toggle webcam from command line?

Tags: command-line, thinkpad, webcam

I am trying to figure out if its possible to -- from within the command-line -- enable/disable the webcam, with a command that can be ran through a keybind? My laptop, a Thinkpad T450 doesn't have a hard switch to turn off the webcam, and it is a security feature I'd really like to have. Preferably something that can be done without a computer restart would be ideal!

Thanks!

Comment: What have you done so far to attempt to accomplish this?

Comment: Found good-looking A's for questions related to [disabling webcam](https://askubuntu.com/q/166809/411468) (permanent and temporary) and [binding commandline to keys](https://askubuntu.com/q/329710/411468).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I disable my webcam?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/166809/how-can-i-disable-my-webcam)

Comment: Sorry I made the post then went to bed hahah. Anyway @l3l_aze that is a workable solution! This morning I found -- on another form -- a solution that can be easily keybound just by using `sudo modprobe -r uvcvideo`. Anyway thx for your help!!