# Using Webcam and Microphone in Virt-Manager

Tags: webcam, microphone, virt-manager, guest-os

I have a Kubuntu 20.04.1 LTS as my Host OS, and I have a Fedora installed as guest using Virt-Manager.

Is it possible to use the built-in Webcam and Microphone of my laptop in the Guest-OS using Virt-Manager? If yes, then how?

Comment: [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1225088/use-webcam-from-laptop-on-desktop-pc) can help, as long as the two OSs have two distinct IPs and you can reach the host IP fron the guest, you can apply the steps for PC on your Guest-OS. This is for Ubuntu though and not Fedora.

Comment: See https://www.linux-kvm.org/page/USB_Host_Device_Assigned_to_Guest

Comment: @user535733 Thanks a lot, this was much simpler!

Comment: @Raffa thanks for your help, but user535733's link to article seemed like a more proper and simpler way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the article that @user535733 posted in comments:

1. Open your VM, go to the `Show virtual Hardware details` menu (the blue "i" icon) at the top.
2. Click on `Add Hardware` -> `USB Host Device` -> Select your Webcam from the list -> `Finish` -> `Apply` your changes.
3. Boot your VM and the webcam should be working. The microphone support exists by default and no additional work is needed for that.

[image]